# How to add a calendar in a fragment on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am currently trying to make an app that requires to have multiple tabs and a calendar in one of them. I used fragments to do the multiple tabs but I didnt find how to implement a calendar in it. I tried to just add it in the xml file by using the palette but I get a null error in my main.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Here is my row_calendar.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Calendar layer"
       />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.nootropicsmonitoringapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.CalendarView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout =findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        getTabs();

    }

    public void getTabs(){
        final  ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(SubstanceListFragment.getInstance(), "Substance List");
                ViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(CalendarFragment.getInstance(), "Calendar");
                ViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(RecapFragment.getInstance(), "Recap");

                viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Any idea what I can change to fix this ?

Thanks for your help !

(Im pretty new to android studio and I didnt find any answer online so Im asking here)

Answer (score 0):

To use View Pager first create an Adapter class like this,

```
public class Adapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

public Adapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    return if (position == 0) {
        new FirstFragment()
    } else {                       // Use Switch Statement here.
        new SecondFragment()
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2; // The number of tabs your Tab Layout has 
}
}
```

And then set this Adapter on your view pager

```
binding.viewPager.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));
```

Setup Tab layout with view pager,

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Now it will work fine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I checked a bit and it seems that I had already an adapter but I was using the decrepated version (ViewPager and not ViewPager2). I migrated it but I still have a few problems with setting up the adapter :
- where does the binding come from ?
- viewPager.setAdapter requires a fragmentActivity, but inputing "this" inputs a Runnable for some reason, what does "this" refer to ?

Comment: I'm using View Binding so from there binding came, but you can just use viewpager because you are using findViewById(). And second you can use MainActivity.this instead of this. It will work.